# When will QGIS be available on Yosemite ?

Tags: qgis, mac

Does anyone know when QGIS will be available on later Versions of Mac OS?

I am on Yosemite and prefer not to go back to Mavericks.

Also, for various reasons I am unable to partition my hard disk and install an older OS version (or Windows).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour]. I think your question is one that can only be answered by someone within the QGIS development team, and I suspect only if that development work is near complete.

Comment: I am having problem with using a plugin in QGIS. I am on OS X EI Capitain.
I installed OSGeo Live on virutal box. Visit https://live.osgeo.org/en/index.html
I don't face any errors anymore.

Comment: Which version of QGIS? Are you after the latest 2.16?

Answer (score 3):

QGIS is currently available for more recent versions of Mac OS than Mavericks. The kynkchaos download page specifically states "Mac OS X installers for QGIS. For OS X Mt Lion and newer". Note the AND NEWER. I'm using v14.3 with El Capitan without problem and ran earlier versions on Yosemite.